# How do I make my CSS-3D cube responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I am trying to make a responsive 3D animated cube that scales with screen size, but anytime i try to change the pixel values to a percentage value, it breaks. How would i make this cube functional and responsive? Here is my code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin-anim {
from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
}
to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
}
@keyframes spin-anim {
from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
}
to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
}
.cube {
-webkit-animation: spin-anim 20s infinite linear;
animation: spin-anim 20s infinite linear;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.canvas {
width:400px;
height:400px;
-webkit-perspective: 500px;
perspective: 500px;
margin:auto;

}
.face {
background-color:blue;
width:400px;
height:400px;
position:absolute;
border:1px solid black;
}
.front {
transform: translateZ(200px);
-webkit-transform:translateZ(200px);
background-image: url(../assets/logo.jpg);
}
.back {
transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(200px);
-webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg) translateZ(200px);
background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/500/500)
}
.top {
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/500/500)
}
.bottom {
transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/500/500)
}
.left {
transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/500/500)
}
.right {
transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/500/500)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n306asn3)

Comment: and the HTML is... ? You can also create a code snippet here or on e.g. jsfiddle

Comment: the html is pretty simple.

`<div class="item3">
 <div class="canvas">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="front face"></div>
        <div class="back face"></div>
        <div class="top face"></div>
        <div class="bottom face"></div>
        <div class="left face"></div>
        <div class="right face"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: the HTML you provide is not working *as is* with your css. And overall, It does not work like that. Nobody will help you if you don't try to look at your question from the answerer's prospective. I cannot help you because you are too lasy to create a fiddle

Comment: Im still new to all this and i have never actually created a fiddle so to be honest I dont know how, its not me being lazy.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ - create a fiddle here, save it and post the a URL in your question. The fiddle should replicate your problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n306asn3/

Here is the fiddle.

Comment: thanks. Already good. However this is the fiddle you should normally give https://jsfiddle.net/n306asn3/1/ . More than half of your code has no relation to the question and is absolutely unnecessary to give here

Answer (score 1):

Look into @media screen

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

The basic idea is that for what ever screen resolution as in (Pixels) the screen of the device is show the css code for that screen size

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
        .cube{
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
        .cube{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    }
```

A small example

Comment: I attempted that, and while there was a change, it didnt quite rescale properly. It seemed to offset to the left, and would only get slightly smaller, and not actually go to the size that i specified. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You might have to change more than just your width and height for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you can use viewport width percentage everywhere in order to be really depending on width only and easily. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n306asn3/3/)

```
@keyframes spin-anim {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
.cube {
    animation: spin-anim 20s infinite linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.canvas {
    width:50vw;
    height:50vw;
    perspective: 200vw;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.face {
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/500/500);
    width:50vw;
    height:50vw;
    position:absolute;
}
.front {
    transform: translateZ(25vw);
}
.back {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(25vw);
}
.top {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(25vw);
}
.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25vw);
}
.left {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(25vw);
}
.right {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(25vw);
}
```

Now every of your cube sides is 50% height / width of the browser window width.

See [more info](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) on `vw`, `vh` and `vmin` (probably `vmin` fits your need even better)